# Using CanActivate and BreakpointObserver in Angular 15

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-route-guards

The Angular 15 suggests using any JavaScript function as a `CanActivate` guard. I want to use `BreakpointObserver` inside this method. I have a `BreakpointService` which takes `BreakpointObserver` as a dependency.

```
export const isMobile = () => {
    return true;
}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, BreakpointState, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Injectable()
export class BreakpointService {

    isDesktop = false;
    isMobile = false;

    constructor(public breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
        this.breakpointObserver
            .observe([Breakpoints.Handset])
            .subscribe((result: BreakpointState) => {
                this.isMobile = result.matches;
                this.isDesktop = !this.isMobile;
            });
    }
}
```

What should I do to inject `BreadkpointService` into the `CanActivate` function to use it's properties `isMobile` or `isDesktop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inject function to resolve dependency

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';    
export function customCanActive(...arg): CanMatchFn {
            const breakpointService = inject(BreakpointService);
            ....
 }
```